Python frameworks for table transformation and validation by row column and cell
I have specific excel tables used as specifications for kafka topic specifications. In the end I must generate avro schemas by the content of the table.
For this first I have to preprocess the table, which means I have to validate and transform the data. The end result of the validations must be some kind of table indicating all the violations of the validation rules by the data contained in the table. By the transformations I mean data cleaning and preprocessing, for example: stripping space characters, make flags uppercase, convert the data types...
I've separated three types of preprocessing category:

Cellwise-preprocessing: validations and transformations applied for each cell value (based on in which field the cell is contained). It has four steps:

pre-validation: apply a list of validation rules for a raw value

transformation: apply a list of transformation on the pre-validated value

post-validation: apply a list of validation rules on the transformed values



Columnwise-validation: validations applied to a column. For each column there is a list of column validation rules defined. The column validation rules needs all the data of a column to work. Currently an is all unique check is the only validation of this kind.

Type-conversion: a functionality defined for each column to convert its values to the desired data type. For example the conversion logic for a flag is like: lambda value: {"Y": True, "N": False}.get(value, np.nan)

Recordwise-validation: Validating a records values by rules working with several columns. For example if the record's value at column_A is True then the value at column_B cannot be null. There is a list of these rules defined. This kind of validation requires clean and type-converted data.
So far im using pandas as the data-manipulator so the base technology is that. The question is more about if is there some more sophisticated frameworks for this kind of data validation and cleaning. I really hope there are some, as in this Data Science driven world a lot of different type of preprocessing of data is required. Or if there are not really suitable fraeworks or libraries, can you suggest some advice about the structure of my preprocessing codes?


so here is an example of how Im doing the cell preprocessing:
class CellValidationRule:

    def __init__(self, rule: Callable[[Any], bool], message: str):
        self.rule = rule
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, value: str) -> bool:
        ret: bool = self.rule(value)
        if not isinstance(ret, bool):
            raise Exception("Validation cannot be applied as the return type is not bool."+
                            f" Return type: {type(ret)}")
        return ret

    def get_message(self, value: str):
        return self.message.replace("$", value) if "$" in self.message else self.message


class CellPreprocessingResult:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value: str = value
        self.messages: list[str] = []
        self.success: bool = True
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.success
    def get_messages(self) -> str:
        return "|".join(self.messages)
    def apply_validation(self, rule: CellValidationRule) -> None:
        result = rule(self.value)
        self.success &= result
        if not result:
            self.messages.append(rule.get_message(value=self.value))
    def apply_transformation(self, transformation: Callable[[str], str]) -> None:
        self.value = transformation(self.value)



class CellRule:
    def __init__(self,
                 pretvalidations: list[CellValidationRule],
                 transformations: list[Callable[[str], str]],
                 postvalidations: list[CellValidationRule]):
        self.pretvalidations = pretvalidations
        self.transformations = transformations
        self.postvalidations = postvalidations

    def run_preprocessing(self, value: Any) -> CellPreprocessingResult:
        # Process value as string but convert back to its original type
        value_type: type = type(value)
        value = str(value)

        # Creating the validation result object.
        result: CellPreprocessingResult = CellPreprocessingResult(value)
        
        # Runnning prevalidations, transformations and postvalidations on the value
        self._run_prevalidation(result)
        self._run_transformations(result)
        self._run_postvalidation(result)
        
        # Change the value type back to the original and returning the result
        result.apply_transformation(value_type)
        return result
        
    def _run_prevalidation(self, result: CellPreprocessingResult) -> None:
        for rule in self.pretvalidations:
            result.apply_validation(rule)

    def _run_transformations(self, result: CellPreprocessingResult) -> None:
        for transformation in self.transformations:
            result.apply_transformation(transformation)

    def _run_postvalidation(self, result: CellPreprocessingResult) -> None:
        for rule in self.postvalidations:
            result.apply_validation(rule)


# Validation rules
_VALIDATE_ACCENTED = CellValidationRule(lambda s: unidecode(str(s)) == s, "Text has accented characters.")
_VALIDATE_SPECIAL_CHAR = CellValidationRule(lambda s: all(c.isalnum() or c=="_" for c in str(s)), "Text contains special characters")
_VALIDATE_SNAKE_CASE = CellValidationRule(
    lambda s: bool(re.match(r"^[A-Z](?:[a-z0-9]*|[A-Z0-9]*)(?:_[A-Z0-9](?:[a-z0-9]*|[A-Z0-9]*))*$", str(s))),
    "Text is not in Snamel_Case")
_VALIDATE_NUMERIC = CellValidationRule(lambda s: str(s).isnumeric(), "Not a numeric value")
_VALIDATE_NOT_NAN = CellValidationRule(not_nan, "Empty value.")
_VALIDATE_FLAG = CellValidationRule(lambda s: s in ["Y","N","YES","NO"], "Value must be Y, N, YES or NO. (case insensitive)")
# Validation rule generators
_GENERATE_VALIDATE_REGEX: Callable[[str], CellValidationRule] = lambda pattern: CellValidationRule(
    lambda s: bool(re.match(pattern, str(s))), f'Not match by validation pattern: "{pattern}"')
_GENERATE_VALIDATE_IN_SET: Callable[[Container[Any]], CellValidationRule] = lambda valid_values: CellValidationRule(
    valid_values.__contains__, f'Invalid value: "$". Valid values: {valid_values}')


# Transformations
_TRANSFORMATION_STRIP = str.strip
_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPACING: Callable[[str], str]        = lambda s: re.sub(r" {2:}", " ", re.sub(r"[\n\t]+", " ", s))
_TRANSFORMATION_UPPER: Callable[[str], str]                 = str.upper
_TRANSFORMATION_UNIDECODE: Callable[[str], str]             = unidecode
_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPEC_CHARS: Callable[[str], str]     = lambda s: re.sub(r"[\W]", "", s)
_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_NON_TEXT_CHARS: Callable[[str], str] = lambda s: re.sub(r"[^\w .,!?áéíóöőúüű]", "", s)
# Transformation generators
_GENERATE_TRANSFORMATION_REPLACE: Callable[[str, str], Callable[[str], str]] = lambda pattern, repl: lambda s: re.sub(pattern, repl, s)


# Declared rules for fields
_RULE_ID = CellRule(
    pretvalidations=[_VALIDATE_ACCENTED, _VALIDATE_SPECIAL_CHAR, _VALIDATE_NOT_NAN],
    transformations=[_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPACING, _TRANSFORMATION_STRIP],
    postvalidations=[_VALIDATE_NUMERIC],
    type_conversion=_CONVERSION_NUMERIC
)
# TODO: Validate key regex
_RULE_KEY = CellRule(
    pretvalidations=[_VALIDATE_ACCENTED],
    transformations=[_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPACING, _TRANSFORMATION_STRIP],
    postvalidations=[]
)
_RULE_TYPE = CellRule(
    pretvalidations=[_VALIDATE_NOT_NAN],
    transformations=[_TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPACING,
                     _TRANSFORMATION_STRIP,
                     _TRANSFORMATION_UNIDECODE,
                     _TRANSFORMATION_UPPER,
                     _TRANSFORMATION_REMOVE_SPEC_CHARS],
    postvalidations=[_GENERATE_VALIDATE_IN_SET(["NUMBER","VARCHAR2","DATE","TIMESTAMP"])]
)


# For this example Im using only three rule-set out of the 14 there is defined in my code.
_RULES = {
    "ID": _RULE_ID,
    "KEY": _RULE_KEY,
    "TYPE": _RULE_TYPE
}

def preprocess_cell(column: str, value: Any) -> CellPreprocessingResult:
    return _RULES[column].run_preprocessing(value)

So that last preprocess_cell I can apply to a dataframe's cell value, and with some simple logic I could get a new data-frame which will contain all the error messages for each field for each record.
I tried to put the type conversion logic to the cell transformations -> it doesnt work as it should work with clean data -> we should apply the conversion logic either by depending on the result of the pre- and post-validation, or the type conversion must be error-resilient -> the type conversion must be a transformation which could validate the value before running by its own requirements -> a failed type conversion should also produce a message to the preprocessing result.
I tried to filter the main dataframe after each category of validation -> records containing values that are failed in any of the cell-wise validations are filtered out before the column- or record-wise validation. -> what if only the value of column_A is failed on the cell-wise validation, but there are multiple record-wise validations that are not depending on the value of column_A -> shall I store for each cell whether it is failed at a previous validation -> what if there are non inclusive validations like a value failed at a cell-wise validation sais: value at column_F can not start with a numeric character, but a record-wise validation sais: the last for character of record value at column_F should be the same as the prefix of the value at column_H -> may I create some kind of validation rule exclusivity table?

I’d would really improve your chances to get an answer if you could boil this down a bit. Frankly: TL;DR.
